# nic: Something Wicked happened! ffff

Tags: debian, linux-networking, linux-kernel, icmp, ethtool

I'm configuring a GNU/Linux Router with Debian Stretch (9.7) and before rebooting the server, all traffic from one interface to another was going ok, but after that, I received a message like this (tty):

```
enp1s6: Something Wicked happened! ffff.
```

I have a host on the same switch and same network, for testing  purposes, and basically, the LAN of the Router is not answering to echo requests.

Here goes some information about the server.

**kernel.log**

```
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.494127] enp1s6: Link changed: 
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.494127] 100Mbps, half duplex
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.494254] enp1s6: Something Wicked happened! ffff.
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.497338] enp1s6: Link up
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.497557] enp1s6: Link changed: 
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.497557] 100Mbps, full duplex
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.499986] enp1s6: Link up
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.500206] enp1s6: Link changed: 
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.500206] 100Mbps, full duplex
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.500447] enp1s6: Link up
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.500667] enp1s6: Link changed: 
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.500667] 100Mbps, full duplex
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.500895] enp1s6: Link up
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.501114] enp1s6: Link changed: 
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.501114] 10Mbps, full duplex
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.501341] enp1s6: Link up
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.501559] enp1s6: Link changed: 
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.501559] 100Mbps, full duplex
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.503985] enp1s6: Link up
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.504204] enp1s6: Link changed: 
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.504204] 100Mbps, full duplex
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.504326] enp1s6: Something Wicked happened! ffff.
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.529009] enp1s6: Link up
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.529229] enp1s6: Link changed: 
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.529230] 100Mbps, full duplex
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.529484] enp1s6: Link up
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.529732] enp1s6: Link changed: 
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.529735] 100Mbps, full duplex
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.531075] enp1s6: Link up
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.531295] enp1s6: Link changed: 
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.531296] 100Mbps, half duplex
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.531531] enp1s6: Link up
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.531751] enp1s6: Link changed: 
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.531751] 100Mbps, full duplex
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.531977] enp1s6: Link up
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.532196] enp1s6: Link changed: 
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.532196] 100Mbps, half duplex
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.532422] enp1s6: Link up
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.532642] enp1s6: Link changed: 
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.532642] 100Mbps, full duplex
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.532869] enp1s6: Link up
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.533089] enp1s6: Link changed: 
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.533090] 100Mbps, full duplex
Jan 25 08:58:02 server001 kernel: [25060.533214] enp1s6: Something Wicked happened! ffff.
```

**lspci (nics): enp0s7 + enp1s6**

```
00:07.0 Bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Ethernet (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd MCP61 Ethernet
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24, NUMA node 0
    Memory at fe02d000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=8]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Capabilities: [6c] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable- Fixed+
    Kernel driver in use: forcedeth
    Kernel modules: forcedeth

01:06.0 Ethernet controller: Sundance Technology Inc / IC Plus Corp IC Plus IP100A Integrated 10/100 Ethernet MAC + PHY (rev 31)
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, NUMA node 0
    I/O ports at b000 [size=128]
    Memory at fde00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at fdf00000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: sundance
    Kernel modules: sundance
```

**ethtool**

```
Settings for enp0s7:
    Supported ports: [ MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 3
    Transceiver: external
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: g
    Wake-on: d
    Link detected: yes

Settings for enp1s6:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  Not reported
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: off
    Supports Wake-on: pg
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000001 (1)
                   drv
    Link detected: yes
```

**ethtool statistics (enp1s6)**

```
NIC statistics:
     tx_multiple_collisions: 26010
     tx_single_collisions: 27540
     tx_late_collisions: 5100
     tx_deferred: 27030
     tx_deferred_excessive: 26010
     tx_aborted: 6630
     tx_bcasts: 27030
     rx_bcasts: 27032
     tx_mcasts: 5610
     rx_mcasts: 27285
```

**ip addr show**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:16:84:16:84:16 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp1s6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:e5:49:64:f6:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.12/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp0s7
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**lsmod**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ip6table_filter        16384  0
ip6_tables             28672  1 ip6table_filter
xt_conntrack           16384  2
nf_conntrack_netlink    36864  0
nfnetlink              16384  6 nf_conntrack_netlink
iptable_filter         16384  1
ipt_MASQUERADE         16384  1
nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4    16384  1 ipt_MASQUERADE
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_conntrack_ipv4      16384  3
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_nat_ipv4            16384  1 iptable_nat
nf_nat                 24576  2 nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_nat_ipv4
nf_conntrack          114688  6 nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_netlink,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,xt_conntrack,nf_nat_ipv4,nf_nat
snd_hda_codec_realtek    90112  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
edac_mce_amd           28672  0
edac_core              57344  0
kvm                   598016  0
evdev                  24576  2
ppdev                  20480  0
serio_raw              16384  0
nouveau              1556480  1
joydev                 20480  0
snd_hda_intel          36864  0
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
snd_hda_codec         135168  3  snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
wmi                    16384  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
snd_hda_core           86016  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
video                  40960  1 nouveau
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
ttm                    98304  1 nouveau
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 nouveau
drm                   360448  4 nouveau,ttm,drm_kms_helper
snd_pcm               110592  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
sg                     32768  0
pcspkr                 16384  0
k10temp                16384  0
parport_pc             28672  0
parport                49152  2 parport_pc,ppdev
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 nouveau
button                 16384  1 nouveau
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
snd                    86016  7 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hdacodec_realtek,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
acpi_cpufreq           20480  0
ip_tables              24576  3 iptable_filter,iptable_nat
x_tables               36864  6 ip_tables,iptable_filter,ipt_MASQUERADE,ip6table_filter,xt_conntrack,ip6_tables
autofs4                40960  2
ext4                  585728  2
crc16                  16384  1 ext4
jbd2                  106496  1 ext4
fscrypto               28672  1 ext4
ecb                    16384  0
glue_helper            16384  0
lrw                    16384  0
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
ablk_helper            16384  0
cryptd                 24576  1 ablk_helper
aes_x86_64             20480  1
mbcache                16384  3 ext4
raid10                 49152  0
raid456               106496  0
async_raid6_recov      20480  1 raid456
async_memcpy           16384  2 raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_pq               16384  2 raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_xor              16384  3 async_pq,raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_tx               16384  5 async_xor,async_pq,raid456,async_memcpy,async_raid6_recov
xor                    24576  1 async_xor
raid6_pq              110592  3 async_pq,raid456,async_raid6_recov
libcrc32c              16384  1 raid456
crc32c_generic         16384  3
raid0                  20480  0
multipath              16384  0
linear                 16384  0
raid1                  36864  1
md_mod                135168  6 raid1,raid10,multipath,linear,raid0,raid456
sd_mod                 49152  7
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 53248  0
hid                   122880  2 hid_generic,usbhid
ata_generic            16384  0
ohci_pci               16384  0
psmouse               135168  0
sata_nv                28672  5
forcedeth              69632  0
ehci_pci               16384  0
libata                249856  2 ata_generic,sata_nv
ohci_hcd               53248  1 ohci_pci
ehci_hcd               81920  1 ehci_pci
scsi_mod              225280  3 sd_mod,libata,sg
usbcore               253952  5 usbhid,ehci_hcd,ohci_pci,ohci_hcd,ehci_pci
sundance               32768  0
mii                    16384  1 sundance
usb_common             16384  1 usbcore
i2c_nforce2            16384  0
```

Any guesses?

Please, be patient: I'm a former SysAdmin (since years), nowadays Software Developer.

Comment: Relevant webcomic to the above error: [CommitStrip - It’s not working!](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2016/03/03/its-not-working/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears your Sundance 10/100 NIC is old, perhaps too old...

See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=748973 (f16 Sundance 10/100 Ethernet module crashes when plugged into gigabit router)

Comment: You bet, dude. It's quite old, supporting 10/100, by the way.
I just putted other NIC here and boom, it started to work normally, without changing a single line in any config file, not even fighting with Kernel modules.
I'll stay with this NIC here (chipset Accton Technology Corp). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Per your ethtool output, I notice enp1s6 is not reporting as supporting auto-negotiation. Is that disabled on the device/port you are connecting too? If possible adjust the device you are connecting with to have auto-negotiation enabled. If you don't have access to that device, or you don't want to change it, then you may have to force a speed/duplix on enp1s6.

Comment: Ok. Makes sense. But, how do I do that (force auto-negotiation on enp1s6)? By the way, I removed this NIC and installed another, which has auto-negotiation by default (according to `ethtool` output for the new NIC), and everything is working fine with the "Router": with my other host on the LAN side, I can ping the LAN NIC of the router, also reaching the Internet. Thanks.